# Blank page while hosting flask with html(render_template issue)

Tags: html, flask

[[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJwx1.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCYhP.jpg)

[app.py code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJJ4q.jpg)

images are my code in app.py and html
where i was trying to render html code and wile try to host there was no error but the html page was blank `(@app.route('/2') def index1(): return render_template('2nd.html')`

but when i was calling
`@app.route('/i') def home(): return "<h2>Hello, World!</h2>"` 
it was displaying
so only blank page while using render_templates.

Comment: The html is missing and it seems that you link the same image twice (app.py), but the html template you wan't to render. You could try with wget / curl from a terminal to see if you get invalid html which can't be rendered by the browser.

Comment: <html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <h1> Welcome to the index page </h1>

</body>
</html>

Comment: above is basic html code i need to display